# NSPredicate by NSManagedObject for many-to-one lookups

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, predicate

I've got the scenario with two NSManagedObjects, Arm and Person. Between them is a many-to-one relationship Person.arms and inverse Arm.owner.

I'd like to write a simple NSPredicate where I've got the `NSManagedObject *arm` and I'd like to fetch the `NSManagedObject *person` that this arm belongs to. I could make a textual representation and look for that, but is there a better way where I can look it up by identity? Something like this perhaps?

```
NSEntityDescription *person = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:MOC];
NSPredicate *personPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN arms", arm];
```

Cheers

Nik

Comment: The real question is "why would you want to?" What are you hoping this will buy you?

Comment: @Joshua I would like to filter a set of data based on an entity in the one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've got the scenario with two NSManagedObjects, Arm and Person. Between them is a many-to-one relationship Person.arms and inverse Arm.owner.
>
> I'd like to write a simple NSPredicate where I've got the `NSManagedObject *arm` and I'd like to fetch the `NSManagedObject *person` that this arm belongs to.

That would be `myArm.owner`. No predicate needed; this is what the inverse relationship is for.

Comment: You are, of course, correct, this is the usual way of going about it. However, I want to reuse a view I have that is using an NSFetchedResultsController, and the arm would be a filter on the NSFetchRequest. Or is there a better way of using this inverse relationship to populate a NSFetchedResultsController?